# How can I use custom style from MapBox with leaflet L.vectorGrid.protobuf

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a custom style, that I made in MapBox. I don't have it in a digital version.

How can I use it with leaflet?

From [here](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#vectorgrid-protobuf) I understand how to add it. But I still need to apply styles. 
From [this](https://jsfiddle.net/avrorab/krys28xc/) example I also understand, how to use my custom MapBox styles with MapBox GL.

But how can I use the custom styles with leaflet VectorGrid protobuf module?

*Btw, I was very impressed with how much faster VectorGrid handles multiple markers or polygons and how fast it can change individual styles on 1000nds of objects*

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet.VectorGrid does **not** have out-of-the-box support for MapBox stylesheets as of today. There was [some preliminary work done](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/commits/mapbox) on that front, but never finished.

The set of technologies that Leaflet.VectorGrid uses internally (an implementation over `L.renderer) is wildly different from the set of technologies that Mapbox.GL uses (creating GLSL shaders out of the style rules). This makes a complete implementation of the stylesheets to be hard work.

On a related note, [support for ESRI stylesheets is also missing](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/147).

Comment: This is also to say: if somebody wants to put in the work needed to finish the work on the `mapbox` branch, please do.